# Prioritize builds within a single Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, priority-queue

I want to run one job multiple times (each build with different parameters) on 2 executors.
I want to execute them based on their build priority value.

Unfortunately Priority Sorter plugin doesn't help in my case, it doesn't sort it correctly - my builds are being executed based on the timestamp they were added to the queue instead of priority.*
I believe this priority mechanism should be implemented before, on a queue level.
How to achieve that?

*-I tested it on the newest Jenkins version and the newest Priority Sorter plugin version

Comment: How are you using the Priority Sorter plugin? are you passing the priority group as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, priority is passed as a build parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should try is Accelerated Build Now plugin. This plugin allows the Jenkins users to launch a build right there, even if the queue is long. It prioritises human launched jobs and brings them to the top.

The Priority Sorter I am using (v3.6.0 and Jenkins v.2.73.3) will not see a job unless you have enabled the Execute Concurrent builds if necessary.

So, allow parallel builds for that job and maybe decrease the number of cores to 1. See if that works. If not, you can try Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin. This allows you to assign as many cores as you want in the specific job.

Comment: Accelerated Build Now plugin moves the build at the top of the queue. However, it doesn't help within multiple execution of single job. Builds are executed based on the order they were launched, instead of queue order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch for [Priority Queue plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7285?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel). For your case it could be [this patch](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel).

Comment: Unfortunately it won't help with sorting multiple concurrent builds for a single job